# How do I anchor my grid cells to the center?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have the grid cells stay centred when I resize the window, but they end up just staying where they are rather than moving closer together. I am trying to replicate the https://rickandmortyapi.com/. I thought it might be better to share the code to my project through codepen: https://codepen.io/Alessandro-Garcia/pen/RwqNaPq

This is the code responsible for taking care of the grid:

```
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(589.19px, auto));
    gap: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

And this is the code responsible for the individual cells:

```
article{
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: You can achieve what you want using `flexbox`. Do you have to use `grid`?

Comment: how would I do that using flexbox? I'm a new programmer...

Comment: I posted an answer, check that out. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using `flexbox` instead of `grid`. Try and add this on your `main` element.

```
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 2000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is also the full example if you want to look around the code too. [Rick and Morty codepen.](https://codepen.io/coolis6/pen/poQgpoW) Hope that helps! :)

For further information on `flexbox` since you mentioned you are new to `CSS` have a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `justify-content: center` on your grid container. CSS tricks has a good [cheat sheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for grid.

I've edited your [codepen](https://codepen.io/adamuk73/pen/wvQMpWg) and literally just added `justify-content: center;` to `main`. Looks to work ok.

Example below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);
  gap: 0.5rem;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container>div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like it doesn't keep the content always center. I tried and resized the window and the content was left aligned.